# objective-c what graphics to use for simple 2d game

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a task of building 2d game (packman style) and I need to use open gl(any version) for drawing image (task says so). It means I should build "open gl application" in Xcode, or it is enough to use Core Graphics or  UIViews?

Comment: Either approach is acceptable.

Comment: Try SDL. It can be used with OpenGL but should also make other aspects of your game much easier to program.

Comment: If "task" = "homework", please say so, otherwise people will downvote - arbitrary restrictions on questions don't go down well without a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very positive experience in my experiments at writing a 2D "packman-style" game using Core Graphics: if you do it right, `CALayer` animation proves sufficiently reliable and simple to implement.

Here is a [link to a great article](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/) that explains how you can implement animated sprites in Cocoa. The trick is to use image atlases to avoid managing multiple images at runtime.